# Agilizar o preenchimento de células em branco no R

Tags: array, r

Eu possuo uma tabela com colunas que possuem várias células em branco e gostaria de preencher essas células com o primeiro valor não-branco acima delas. Eu sei fazer isso usando o script abaixo, mas gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de agilizar/acelerar esse processo.

`for (i in 1:ncol(tab)) for (j in 1:nrow(tab)) if (is.na(tab[i,j])) tab[i,j] <- tab[(i-1),j]`

Agradeço desde já a quem puder ajudar.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: A função `na.locf` (*"locf"* significa *"last observation carried forward"*) do pacote `zoo` serve exatamente para isso.

Comment: E se o primeiro valor de uma coluna for `NA`, fica na mesma?

Comment: Obrigado a todos pelas respostas e comentários. Embora o bot da comunidade tenha achado difícil identificar o que eu estava perguntando, os colegas Rui Barradas e Carlos Eduardo Lagosta responderam exatamente o que eu precisava.

Comment: Quanto à pergunta do Rui Barradas, nos bancos de dados que utilizo a primeira linha nunca tem NA. Por isso, ao menos no meu caso específico, essa pergunta não se aplica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Além da função `zoo::na.locf` indicada na [resposta de Rui Barradas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/574779/117168), pode usar `tidyr::fill` (com a opção `.direction = "down"`, a padrão) ou `data.table::nafill` (com a opção `type = "locf"`).

```
# Dados de exemplo
set.seed(786)
dados <- setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:3, NA), 36, TRUE), 6)), LETTERS[1:6])

dados
#>    A  B C  D  E  F
#> 1 NA  1 1  1  1 NA
#> 2  1  1 1 NA NA NA
#> 3  2 NA 2  2  1 NA
#> 4  1  2 3 NA  1  2
#> 5  2  1 2 NA  3  3
#> 6 NA  1 1 NA  2  3
```

### tidyr

```
library(tidyr)

fill_(dados, names(dados))
#>    A B C D E  F
#> 1 NA 1 1 1 1 NA
#> 2  1 1 1 1 1 NA
#> 3  2 1 2 2 1 NA
#> 4  1 2 3 2 1  2
#> 5  2 1 2 2 3  3
#> 6  2 1 1 2 2  3
```

### data.table

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dados)

dados[, lapply(.SD, nafill, type = "locf")]
#>     A B C D E  F
#> 1: NA 1 1 1 1 NA
#> 2:  1 1 1 1 1 NA
#> 3:  2 1 2 2 1 NA
#> 4:  1 2 3 2 1  2
#> 5:  2 1 2 2 3  3
#> 6:  2 1 1 2 2  3
```

Usando `set` para atualizar as colunas por referência:

```
setnafill(dados, "locf")

dados
#>     A B C D E  F
#> 1: NA 1 1 1 1 NA
#> 2:  1 1 1 1 1 NA
#> 3:  2 1 2 2 1 NA
#> 4:  1 2 3 2 1  2
#> 5:  2 1 2 2 3  3
#> 6:  2 1 1 2 2  3
```

Answer (score -1):

O pacote `zoo` tem uma função, [`na.locf`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/zoo/html/na.locf.html),  que resolve o problema da pergunta.

```r
# dados de teste
set.seed(2023)
dados <- head(mtcars, 10)
dados[] <- lapply(dados, \(x) {is.na(x) <- sample(length(x), 4); x})

dados[] <- lapply(dados, zoo::na.locf, na.rm = FALSE)
dados
#>                    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4         21.0  NA    NA 110   NA 2.620    NA NA NA    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0  NA 160.0 110 3.90 2.620    NA  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        21.0   4 108.0 110 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    4
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258.0 110 3.85 3.215 19.44  1  1    3    4
#> Hornet Sportabout 21.4   8 258.0 175 3.85 3.440 19.44  0  1    3    2
#> Valiant           18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.440 19.44  1  1    3    1
#> Duster 360        14.3   8 360.0 105 3.21 3.440 15.84  1  0    3    1
#> Merc 240D         14.3   8 360.0 105 3.21 3.190 20.00  1  0    3    1
#> Merc 230          14.3   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.190 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> Merc 280          19.2   4 140.8 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>